# How to set Azure VM that has the same IP as the machine where we are remoting from

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I would like that my Azure VM has the same IP as the machine, which we are remoting from.
Is it possible to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Your ask is not possible. You cannot have a VM with overlapping address space that of the Source.